# Retention policy on site level

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

Retention policies are disabled on tenant level at the moment. As end user I also have no option to access the admin center.

How is it possible to create a retention policy or option on site level by site owners?
Or how can we manage to periodically delete files which are older than x years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, site owners could create a retention policy in the site level.

Go to the document library settings -> Information management policy settings -> Choose the Document content type -> In the Retention section -> Enable Retention -> Add a retention stage.

[image]

Comment: The option is hidden inmy environment. Can you share the URL to the option screen? ( .../emilytestnew/_layouts/15/retention ...... )

Comment: Found the solution to activate the option: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of retention label action you want to apply at the site level. If you want to perform an out-of-scope action from the site retention policy like "**Move to recycle Bin**", "**Permanently Delete**", "**Start a workflow**", "**Skip to next stage**", "**Declare record**", "**Delete previous draught**", and "**Delete all previous versions**,"  these actions run in the context of the current site, so with the site owner's permission, we can implement this type of site-level retention policy. However, suppose if we want to create a custom connection that will copy or move data from one site to another site through the routing rules or without routing rules, we need to create the custom connection in the SharePoint Online Admin Centre with the access of the tenant administrator, or at least by the SharePoint Online tenant administrator.

Having said that, we can also look at the modern retention label rather than the traditional retention policy, which works on a top down-hierarchical approach, like applying the retention label to the document library label, folder label, document label, etc. For more details on modern retention level you may refer to this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention?view=o365-worldwide).